# Theano, structured v.s. regular gradient

Tags: theano

I don't know whether SO is a good place to ask this question, but I can't find the document talking about the different between structured gradient and regular gradient in the Theano library. What are they ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean with respect to sparse operations?

As mentioned [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/other_ops.html#sparse-gradient).

> There are 2 types of gradients for sparse operations: normal gradient
>   and structured gradient.

The difference only applies to sparse matrices because with sparse matrices you may or may not care about the effect of the "empty space" in a sparse matrix on the gradients.

More [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/sandbox/sparse.html#dot-vs-structureddot).